# Show/Hide a group of polyline in Google Map Android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm doing a simple project that can trace user's positions and plot these locations using `Polyline`. Now I want to add a check box to toggle whether to display these lines or not. The challenge I think is that I have many polylines here so I don't know how to set all of them invisible/visible at the same time.

Maybe I can draw them on a layer then toggle visibility of that layer? I'm just guessing..

Does anyone know how to do it?  Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
Probably not very related but I'll still show how I add polyline once detect user move

```
   PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();

   options.add(lastLoc, curLoc);

   mMap.addPolyline(options.color(Color.RED).width(3));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a single [`Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) which is initially empty (back to that later) just after you acquire reference to `GoogleMap`.

After you get a location update add a point to this `Polyline` with the (ugly, because there is no `Polyline.addPoint`) code below:

```
List<LatLng> points = polyline.getPoints();
points.add(currentLocationLatLng);
polyline.setPoints(points);
```

When you need to hide it, use `polyline.setVisible(false);`.

So now you don't have to worry about a bunch of short polylines, but just one long.

**Not always initially empty:**
To make sure you don't lose on user experience when rotating the phone or process being killed in background, you have to "persist" all the points. `onSaveInstanceState` should be enough.

Comment: just realize you have answered my latest three questions..thx a lot~

Comment: already read this http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#setPoints(java.util.List<com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng>) but its not very helpfull!

Comment: `Create a single Polyline which is initially empty` How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

To set all of them at one time, add every `lastLoc` and `curLoc` into a List, and then use `options.addAll(List)`

You will display all polylines at once, thus you can remove/hide them together if you want :)

**EDIT : Some Example**

init the `List` :

`List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();`

Insert each `curLoc` & `lastLoc` into `points` :

```
while (!traceFinished.equals(true)){
     points.add(curLoc); //read every new current location
}
points.add(lastLoc); //the final location, after the trace stopped
```

to display the polyline, you can then call :

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
options.addAll(points);
mMap.addPolyline(options.color(Color.RED).width(3));
```

Good Luck

Comment: thanks, and it works. The only thing for this method is that every time when adding new position to the polyline, I have to remove the big polyline and redraw so I don't know if this is the best way.(I update my polyline whenever user moves, so there's no while loop in my code and I 'append' polylines each time ) If no better answer appear this week, I'll definitely accept this for sure. :)

Comment: that's fine, as long as the polyline is removed and redrawed, there should be no memory leak or something like that :)